# Chirpy console throws exception

Tags: minify, chirpy

I want to run the Chirpy console minifyer, but it throws exception. The path given exists and earlier it ran impeccably. I'm not sure what might cause the problem. Can someone explain it to me? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were too many compiles in a short period of time. The service temporarily becomes unavailable in this case.